# most effective way to write query selecting null and not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to select patients who have plannumbers that are null and not null, here is my effort:

```
select distinct PatientID from Visits where plannumber is null and 
patientid = (
select distinct patientid from Visits where plannumber is not 
null group by PatientID) group by PatientID
```

That returns and error 'subquery returns more than 1 value'.

Is there a more effective way to write this query?

Comment: I guess this query won't return anything. It is like `where plannumber is null and plannumber is not null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct V1.PatientID 
  from Visits V1
  join Visits V2 
    on V2.PatientID = V1.PatientID 
   and V1.plannumber is not null 
   and V2.plannumber is null
```

or

```
select distinct PatientID 
  from Visits 
 where plannumber is not null
INTERSECT 
select distinct PatientID 
  from Visits 
 where plannumber is null
```

as for your query

```
patientid in
```

not

```
patientid =
```

And your distinct and group by is redundant

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways, here are a couple...

```
SELECT
  PatientID
FROM
  Visits
GROUP BY
  PatientID
HAVING
      SUM(CASE WHEN plannumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN plannumber IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Patient
WHERE
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE plannumber IS     NULL AND PatientID = Patient.ID)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE plannumber IS NOT NULL AND PatientID = Patient.ID)
```

Comment: why so complicated? It's just simple select distinct PatientID from Visits.

Comment: you have a typo in your second query: there is no Patient table

Comment: @I.K. - Actually, no it's not, based on the OP's question each patient can have multiple rows in the Visits table.  The OP wants patients that have at least two rows; one that has a NULL plannumber, and one that has a NOT NULL plannumber.  As for the missing `patient` table, it's highly likely to exist in a correctly formed database.